# Download multiple files - Selenium/Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

What is the correct way of preventing current version of Chrome, running via Selenium, from showing the following dialog:

> localhost:8444 wants to download multiple files. Block / Allow.

when the website under test triggers two file downloads? Both files are generated in the browser using `URL.createObjectURL()`, `Blob` and dynamically appended anchor.

I did try several profile settings described in other answers, but they seem to no longer work with the most recent Chrome 62:

```
"download.directory_upgrade" "true"
"safebrowsing.enabled" "true"
"profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.https://localhost:8444,*.setting" 1
"profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.https://localhost:8444,*.last_modified" 0
"profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.last_modified" 0
"profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting" 1
"profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads" 1
"profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads" 2
```

I tried all of the above, individually and in certain permutations.

- Chrome 62
- Chromedriver 2.32
- Selenium 3.6

Comment: It works with `"profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting": 1` with Chrome 62 and chromedriver 2.33. Update your driver and make sure that you are correctly setting the preference.

Comment: @FlorentB.Wow, you're right. I did actually set the Chrome profile incorrectly when running Selenium locally. Interestingly, I never noticed that before. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll happily accept that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. After updating as mentioned by @FlorentB. its working fine for 
chrome 66
chrome driver 2.36
webdriver 3.8

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting", 1);
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.prefs", chromePrefs);
```